# Broken pointer when returned, but works when allocated

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, malloc

I'm working on a sample project, that would firstly work with serial algorithm, and then write a CUDA parallel implementation to compare the results and speed.

The project is a simple Connect Four game.
Here is a [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfNYI.jpg) of the game if you don't recognize it by its name.

So, because I'll reuse code for the CUDA implementation that has to work with cudaMalloc and cudaMemcpy, I'm creating the serial implementation using malloc.

My problem is in my GameBoard class, that contains methods for initialization and access to the fields. I'm allocating the matrix using:

```
this->board = static_cast<int*>(malloc(sizeof(int) * GameBoard::BOARD_SIZE));

for (int i = 0; i < GameBoard::BOARD_SIZE; i++)
{
    this->board[i] = 0;
}
```

**I'm not using calloc to keep it as similar to the CUDA implementation, as there is no cudaCalloc*

Where `BOARD_SIZE` is:

```
static const int BOARD_HEIGHT = 6;
static const int BOARD_WIDTH = 7;
static const int BOARD_SIZE = BOARD_HEIGHT * BOARD_WIDTH;
```

I have to use one array and do the math and pretend it's a matrix, for a easy CUDA implementation later (pointer of pointers kind of array is not a good idea on GPU).

This is my method for getting a piece with the "math":

```
int GameBoard::getPiece(int x, int y)
{
    std::cout << x * GameBoard::BOARD_WIDTH + y << ", ";
    std::cout << this->board[x * GameBoard::BOARD_WIDTH + y];
    return this->board[x * GameBoard::BOARD_WIDTH + y];
}
```

And this is where I call it, in a printBoard() method that should print the current board state:

```
void GameBoard::printBoard()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_HEIGHT; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < BOARD_WIDTH; j++)
            std::cout << getPiece(i, j) << "  ";
    ...
}
```

And what I'm getting as a result is, a matrix full of the "broken pointer" value of **-572662307**. But if I paste the loops with testing output in the initialization method, it prints out zeros, as it should be doing.

Why am I getting this behavior where in one method the pointer is working fine, and in the next method it's completely broken? I'm using the same getPiece() method to access elements, and there is nothing in between those two method calls, they're literally called one after another as:

```
// in main
game.startGame();
game.runGame();

// initialization in startGame() with the constructor
this->game_board_ = GameBoard();

// first step in game loop of runGame(), nothing else is done before
game_board_.printBoard();
```

Comment: Tell me what the line `this->game_board_ = GameBoard();` does, in detail

Comment: I allocate a private property game_board_, which is a Class with the methods listed and the allocated array.
The constructor contains the _I'm allocating the matrix using:_ block of code above and nothing else

Comment: @molbdnilo I'm using malloc, because I thought it will be easier for me when I'll port the implementation to CUDA, I'll know that the allocation with cudaMalloc is working and I'll need less changes

Comment: `this->game_board_ = GameBoard();` - that's an *assignment*. Did you write a proper implementation of copy-assignment operator for `GameBoard` class? What about The Rule of Three in general?

Comment: @Galvanic Sure but what do your assignment operator and destructor contain? Because `this->game_board_ = GameBoard();` calls all three of those

Comment: @Galvanic -- Please post `GameBoard`.

Comment: Well, I've obviously gotten rusty with C++, and this is the exact problem I had. I forgot that I have to overload my assignment operator, but didn't forget to overload the destructor and no assignment overload probably did all the trouble.

Thanks guys!